# java hirerequest() and processhirerequest() methods

Tags: java

Hi guys i have created two different classes which are a shopitem class and a shopuser class, I need to create two methods, hirerequest() and processhirerequest: below is my attempt at coding which has been unsucessful and will not compile:

```
/**
    * Accessor method hireRequest
    *
    * @return shopuser and shopitem object's
    */
   public String hireRequest()
   {
      return shop item object;
      return shop user object;  
   }



/**
    * Accessor method processHireRequest
    *
    * @return name
    */
   public String processHireRequest()
   {
      return hireRequest;
   }
```

is this above code correct and should it work??

any answers or help would be greatly appreciated.

code Shopitem:

```
public abstract class ShopItem
{
   private ArrayList<Tool> toolsList;
   Shop shop;
   private int toolCount;
   private String toolName;
   private int power;
   private int timesBorrowed;
   private boolean rechargeable;
   private int itemCode;
   private int cost;
   private double weight;
   private boolean onLoan;
   private static JFrame myFrame;
   private String Tool;
   private String ElectricTool;
   private String HandTool;
   private String Perishable;
   private String Workwear;
   private boolean ShopUserID;


   public void ReadToolData (String data) throws FileNotFoundException,NoSuchElementException
    {
    //    shows the directory of the text file
    File file = new File("E:/LEWIS BC 2/java project/project 1 part 3/ElectricToolData.txt");
    Scanner S = new Scanner (file);
    // prints out the data
    System.out.println();
    // prints out the
    System.out.println();
    S.nextLine();
    S.nextLine();
    S.nextLine();
    S.nextLine();
    S.nextInt ();



} 


   /**
    * Creates a collection of tools to be stored in a tool list
    */
 public ShopItem(String toolName, int power,int timesborrowed,boolean rechargeable,int itemCode,int cost,double weight,int toolcount,boolean onLoan,boolean ShopUserID)
   {
      toolsList = new ArrayList<Tool>();
      toolName = new String();
      power = 0;
      timesborrowed = 0;
      rechargeable = true;
      itemCode = 001;
      cost = 100;
      weight = 0.0;
      toolCount = 0;
      onLoan = true;
//       ShopUserID = null;
   }

   /**
     * Default Constructor for Testing
     */
    public ShopItem()
    {
        // initialise instance variables


        toolName = "Spanner";
        itemCode = 001;
        timesBorrowed = 0;
        power = 0;
        onLoan = true;
        rechargeable = true;
        itemCode = 001;
        cost = 100;
        weight = 0.0;
        toolCount = 0;

    }


 /**
    * Reads ElectronicToolData data from a text file 
    *
    * @param   <code>fileName</code> a <code>String</code>, the name of the 
    *          text file in which the data is stored.
    * 
    * @throws  FileNotFoundException
    */   
    public void readData(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
//   
//     while (there are more lines in the data file )
// {
//    lineOfText = next line from scanner
//    if( line starts with // ) 
//       { // ignore }          
//    else if( line is blank )  
//       { // ignore }          
//    else
//       { code to deal with a line of ElectricTool data }
// }


      myFrame = new JFrame("Testing FileDialog Box");
      myFrame.setBounds(200, 200, 800, 500);
      myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      myFrame.setVisible(true);

    { 
        FileDialog fileBox = new FileDialog(myFrame,
                      "Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
      fileBox.setVisible(true);
}

    {
       File dataFile = new File(fileName);
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);

      while( scanner.hasNext() )
      {
         String info = scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.println(info);
      }
      scanner.close();
    }
}

 /**
     * Default Constructor for Testing
     */
    public void extractTokens(Scanner scanner) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        // extracts tokens from the scanner

        File text = new File("E:/LEWIS BC 2/java project/project 1 part 3/items_all.txt");



        String ToolName = scanner.next();
        int itemCode = scanner.nextInt();
        int cost = scanner.nextInt();
        int weight = scanner.nextInt();
        int timesBorrowed = scanner.nextInt();
        boolean rechargeable = scanner.nextBoolean();
        boolean onLoan = scanner.nextBoolean();

        extractTokens(scanner);

        // System.out.println(parts.get(1)); // "en"
    }

   /**
    * Creates a tool collection and populates it using data from a text file
    */
   public ShopItem(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      this();
      ReadToolData(fileName);
   }

   /**
    * Adds a tool to the collection
    *
    * @param   <code>tool</code> an <code>Tool</code> object, the tool to be added
    */
   public void storeTool(Tool tool)
   {
      toolsList.add(tool);
   }

   /**
    * Shows a tool by printing it's details.  This includes
    * it's position in the collection.
    *
    * @param  <code>listPosition</code> the position of the animal
    */
   public void showTool(int listPosition)
   {
      Tool tool;
      if( listPosition < toolsList.size() )
      {
         tool = toolsList.get(listPosition);
         System.out.println("Position " + listPosition  + ": " + tool);
      }
   }

   /**
    * Returns how many tools are stored in the collection
    *
    * @return   the number of tools in the collection
    */
   public int numberOfToolls()
   {
      return toolsList.size();
   }

   /**
    * Displays all the tools in the collection
    *
    */
   public void showAllTools()
   {
      System.out.println("Shop");
      System.out.println("===");

      int listPosition = 0;
      while( listPosition<toolsList.size() )  //for each loop
      {
         showTool(listPosition);
         listPosition++;
      }
      System.out.println(listPosition + " tools shown" );    // display number of tools shown  
   }

   public void printAllDetails()
   {

// The name of the file to open.
        String fileName = "ElectricToolDataNew.txt";

        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = null;


        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = 
                new FileReader(fileName);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }   

            // Always close files.
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                fileName + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + fileName + "'");                  
            // Or we could just do this: 
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

code Shopuser

```
public abstract class ShopUser
{
   private String name;
   Shop shop;
   private String shopUserID;
   private String itemCode;

   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class ShopUser
    */
   public ShopUser(String name, String shopUserID)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.shopUserID = shopUserID;
      this.itemCode = itemCode;
   }

// /**
//     * Accessor method hireRequest
//     *
//     * @return shopuser and shopitem object's
//     */
//    public void hireRequest(String shopItem, String shopUser)
//    {
//       return shopItem;
//       return shopUser;   
//    }

   /**
    * Accessor method getName
    *
    * @return name
    */
   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }

    /**
    * Accessor method getShopUserID
    *
    * @return shopUserID
    */
   public String getShopUserID()
   {
      return shopUserID;
   }

   /**
    * Method extractTokens that extracts tokens for a ShopUser object from a
    * line of text that has been passed to the scanner
    *
    */
   public void extractTokens(Scanner scanner)
   {
      // data is name, shopUserID
      name = scanner.next();
      shopUserID = scanner.next();
   }

   /**
    * Accessor method printDetails
    */
   public void printDetails()
   {
      System.out.printf("%-15s %s %n", "name:", name);
      System.out.printf("%-15s %s %n", "shop user ID:", shopUserID);
   }

}
```

Comment: This certainly won't compile. Could you post the code for the classes themselves so that we can better understand what's going on?

Comment: edited post to include code

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to create a method which will allow users to hire an item using a hirerequest() method and then the hirerequest will call a new processhirerquest method in shopuser.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String hireRequest() {
   return shop item object;
   return shop user object;  
}
```

A method can only return ONE item.

Shop user object is never being called. You should have separate getters for shopUser and shopItem.